# Facebook for webpage embeded

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe

I want to embed the `#FIFA` hashtag which shared on Facbook as an `iframae` on my webpage , 
I tried using `iframe` but Facebook doesn't support `iframes`.

also using `JSON` output

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23fifa&access_token=CAAA....
```

but the `access_token` expires after one hour.

Please advice me how to proceed to add  dynamic web page for displaying `#fifa` hashtag shares on my site like Twitter widget.